# What C# library provides lossless video compression?

Tags: c#, video, compression, lossless

I was wondering what a good library would be for doing c# lossless video compression? I have a lot of hard drive space so that's not an issue. Only lossless will do, no alternatives.
thanks

I was also thinking something like http://zlib.net/ wrapping the data, but is there any codec that would be able to unwrap it and play it, or does anyone have any ideas how to make something like that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make an AVI using a lossless codec, such as [Lagarith](http://lags.leetcode.net/codec.html).  There are various options for making AVI files from images, such as this [C# wrapper for AviFile](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx).

Comment: That wrapper class seems to spit out bad avi files. They play, but the time is screwed up it seems.

Comment: Settings seem fine. I use the example, and don't set any compression or anything, set it to 30fps, no compression. Bmp image format.

Comment: Ran it through an avi fixer, and it spits out all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

- http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-code-samples/
- http://www.mitov.com/html/videolab_tutorials.html